# Searching an arraylist of objects for a user given phrase

Tags: java, string, for-loop, search, arraylist

My program has a user add a customer name and customer phone number to an arraylist. Then if the user wants they can search(the arraylist) for a customer depending on what they enter in. If the user enters a name of "nate" and only types in nat to search. It is supposed to display all matches that contain nat.

I can't seem to use the for loop correctly and if it does. It only matches exact content when I use the .equals method.

---

Now that I have updated the .equals to .contains. The new problem is that the 
for (Customer c : customers ) is not working. Customer is my class that creates the object, customers is the arraylist containing the Customer objects.

At: for (Customer c :
Error message says:

> Error:(107, 31) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Customer>

```
public class CustomerDirectory
{
    //Shorten Scanner
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    static ArrayList customers = new ArrayList();


    public static void main(String[] args)
 ......
 .......
```

---

method in main class that adds a customer name and phone number to the arraylist.

```
    public static void addCustomer()
{

    System.out.print("Enter new name: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter new phone number: ");
    String number = keyboard.nextLine();

    Customer newCustomer = new Customer(name, number);
    customers.add(newCustomer);

}
```

---

```
    public static void findCustomer()
{
    System.out.print("Enter name of customer to find: ");
    String findName = keyboard.nextLine();
    findName = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (findName.equals(" "))
    {
        System.out.println("You did not enter a name.");
    }
    else
    {
        for (Customer c : customers )
        {
            if (c.getCustomerName().contains(findName) )
            {
                System.out.println(c.getCustomerName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Class that creates the objects to go into the array list.
    class Customer
    {
    static String customerName;
    String telePhone;

```
public Customer(String customerName, String telePhone)
{
    setCustomerName(customerName);
    setTelePhone(telePhone);
}

public static String getCustomerName()
{
    return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName)
{
    //Make the user input lowercase
    customerName = customerName.toLowerCase();
    if (customerName.equals(""))
    {
        System.out.println("You did not enter a name. Did not create new                      
    customer.");
    }
    else if (customerName.length() > 25)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName.substring(0, 25);
    }
    else
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

}

public String getTelePhone()
{
    return telePhone;
}

public void setTelePhone(String telePhone)
{
    if (telePhone.equals(""))
    {
        System.out.println("You did not enter a telephone number. Did not   
    create new customer.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.telePhone = telePhone;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post code in the question, not in links, and definitely not as images. Links have a tendency to die, and images can't be executed by those reading the question.

Comment: Please excuse any errors caused by the soft wraps.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: search is a big topic in CS, please be more specific and post some code and identify your problems.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `String.contains` instead of `String.equals`.

Comment: why do you have `findName = keyboard.nextLine();` twice ? you only want to accept the customer name once from the user ?

Comment: In regards to the two lines. When I did just the one. It wasn't waiting for the scanner. It just kept skipping it, I found if I put in the 2nd one, it paused for the user to enter a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList reference requires type for declaration.
You have not mentioned any type in ArrayList object creation, so it is taking customers as type object.

Try replacing your main class as below

```
public class CustomerDirectory {
    // Shorten Scanner
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    static ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    ......
    ......
```

This line is important: `static ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();`

Comment: This was the root problem....thank you so much. The chapter in my book didn't cover this...

Answer (score 1):

try changing your `if` condition to :

`if (c.getCustomerName().contains(findName) )`

> The java.lang.String.contains() method returns true if and only if
>   this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Also, you do not need 2 lines for accepting user input :

`String findName = keyboard.nextLine();
    findName = keyboard.nextLine();`

Remove the second line.

Comment: I have changed it to .contains method. In regards to the two lines. When I did just the one. It wasn't waiting for the scanner. It just kept skipping it, I found if I put in the 2nd one, it paused for the user to enter a name.

Comment: Error message says it 
>found 'Customer. Required Object>  posted more detail in original post.

Comment: does it say where the error occurs ?

Comment: for (Customer c : is where the error is.

Comment: can u show where u are creating the customers arraylist ?

Comment: Added the code. Its in the ...I cant think of a good name..not main class..but the first class I made. Sorry I'm feeling a bit , like I'm not good at this stuff.

Comment: yeah, like the above answer says, when initializing or declaring an arraylist you also need to mention the type of arraylist you are creating.

Comment: I figured this is what you were going to check next. I wish I could somehow give you a "right answer" point as well. Thank you for your help, sometimes I wonder if I'm not the programmer type :/

Comment: glad i could help :)